# Python: how to ignore special characters when parsing through strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am parsing through rows and cells in excel files and write to a csv file. I ran into a `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode....`
I fixed this by adding `.encode("utf-8")` after the variable. But this output a `b'.....'` to the string.
What if I don't want this encoding. I dont want these special characters.

How can I skip these characters or this error?
Here are my code:

```
import csv
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = "C:/Complete_XLSX/"
file_lists = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
import xlrd

data_writer = csv.DictWriter(open('downloaded_data.csv', 'w', newline=''),
                             fieldnames=['fund_ticker', 'constituent_ticker', 'Name',
                                         'Detail_Holding_Type', 'Date', 'Holding'])
data_writer.writeheader()

for file in file_lists:
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(f'{mypath}{file}')
    sheet_names = book.sheet_names()
    for sheet in book.sheets():
        fund = sheet.name[0: sheet.name.find('_')]
        for row in sheet.get_rows():
            for col in range(3, sheet.ncols):
                date = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sheet.cell_value(0, col), book.datemode)
                date_str = date[0] * 10000 + date[1] * 100 + date[2]
                if row[col].value:
                    try:
                        data_writer.writerow({'fund_ticker': fund, 'constituent_ticker': row[0].value,
                                          'Name': row[1].value.encode("utf-8"), 'Detail_Holding_Type': row[2].value,
                                          'Date': date_str, 'Holding': row[col].value})
```

Comment: You probably need to `open(...)` the file to write to using `encoding='utf-8'`. But we'd need to see a representative code snippet to be able to say for sure.

Comment: @deceze I added my code, can you please open the post?

Comment: As I thought, add `encoding='utf-8'` to that `open(...)` call…?

Comment: Yes, But this woull still output the special characters to the CSV. How do I skip these characters?

Comment: You would then need to define what exactly "special characters" are. Anything "non-ASCII"? Non-Latin-1? If you can properly output them now, why'd you want to discard them instead? Doesn't that lose information?

Comment: These characters don't add value. They include, for example, the letter R with a circle around. I tried adding `encoding='utf-8' ` to the open(...) but it does not work with the `csv.DictWriter.writerow`

Comment: nevermind. I got it to work now. thanks